# Implement a "system config"-like page

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I'm interested in creating an accordion layout just like the main system configuration pages. This means I want to have sections which you can expand vertically and then see its content, basically the same as in the System > Configuration page, but on a different page of course and with my own content.

What I have:

- the page in the backend
- an accordion block with child elements but without content

What I need to know:

- what is the standard way of creating content for the accordion block compareable to the system > config page (a descriptor on the left and a content field on the right, depending on the type of content needed)?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please explain it in detail as it is not quite clear what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: If you need to add config section, there's no need to implement accordion - all implementation should be done in system.xml file of your module.

Comment: @Dexter please see my edit

Comment: @DmitryR I want a page LIKE the config page on a page from my module (admin/<modulename>/...)

Comment: You want your module's configuration page on left in administrator's menu? If so refer to this: ```http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_add_a_custom_module_for_custom_admin_config_options```

Comment: @versedi no, I want to display data from my module SIMILARLY but NOT WITHIN the administrator's menu. I want to replicate this style to my own page

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to do this?

Comment: @MaikelKoek well, because I think it looks nice and it suits the data I want to display (categorized items with metadata you can edit - just like the admin pages)

Comment: Well then I'm not sure why you don't want to use the configuration pages? You can create your own menu item for example and link to the correct page directly, and the config has a lot of nice functionalities (depending, renderering, etc). You can show a block with content (explanation or anything) above the config tabs if you like.

Comment: @MaikelKoek well, it's part of an import dialog, so users shouldn't be able to change those settings afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the involved components; you will likely be able to remove much of the contents as your import/export module will probably not have the complicated scope/view logic.

---

### Controller

`Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController`

---

### Blocks

- **Tabs:** `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Tabs (Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget)` & `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Dwstree (Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs)`
- **Form:** `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form (Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form)` & `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit (Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget)`
- **Fieldsets:** `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Fieldset`
- **Fields:** `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Fields`

---

### Templates

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/config/`

---

There is also an admin config data model which handles a lot of the access and scope details.

Comment: Follow up: How does `Mage_Core_Model_Config_System` factor in? `Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesConfiguration()` does not seem to leverage it but instead does the same thing in it's foreach loop as the `core/config_system` model does in it's `load()` method.

Comment: holy crap, that's precisely what I was looking for :) also interested in what @Melvyn has asked